# Can't connect to an instance on AWS EC2 with a new key pair (I lost the old one)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I lost the private key of my *original instance* on AWS EC2, and I expend 2.5 days looking for a solution, in vain.

#### Following the instructions of AWS help...

I created another key pair, launched a *new instance* with a *new volume* and achieved a SSH connection. Then I stopped the *new instance*, attached the *original volume* as an auxiliar volume of the *new instance* and started the *new instance*. Curiously, I couldn't connect. (yes, I used the new Public DNS - after stop/start).

Then I stoped the *new instance*, detached the *original volume*, started the *new instance*  again, and it connected. With the instance running, I attached the *original volume*, mounted it and changed the *.ssh/authorized_keys* of the original volume to the *new key pair*:

```
[ubuntu ~]$ cp .ssh/authorized_keys /mnt/originalvol/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

I umounted the volume, stoped the instance, detached the *original volume* and attached it to the *original instance*, turned it on and... *Permission denied*.

Then I tried variations between the instance and volumes, but every time the *original volume* was attached (as main or as auxiliar volume), I couldn't connect.

#### Following isntructions of other questions like this in this site...

I tryed to create an AMI of my original instance and volume, and create a new instance/volume based on the AMI, but it doesn't work.

I'm trying to avoid to copy all my website files into a new instance/volume and configurate it all again.

Can anyone help to find a solution to this issue?

Thanks

Saulo

---

EDIT#1: The log of the command ssh...

```
saulo@saulo-VirtualBox:~/ssh_keys$ ssh -v -i GeorgeTeste.pem ubuntu@ec2-52-33-160-205.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to ec2-52-33-160-205.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com [52.33.160.205] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file GeorgeTeste.pem type -1
debug1: identity file GeorgeTeste.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.3 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 24:52:41:2d:c5:f7:ea:1c:56:cd:e9:3d:37:56:de:14
debug1: Host 'ec2-52-33-160-205.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/saulo/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: GeorgeTeste.pem
debug1: key_parse_private2: missing begin marker
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
saulo@saulo-VirtualBox:~/ssh_keys$
```

Comment: After you copy the authorized_keys to originalvol, change the permission to 600, and try again. Make sure you use the new key.


chmod 600 /mnt/originalvol/home/ubuntu/.ssh/authorized_keys

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I'm still getting "Permission denied".

Comment: then some other information is mising. what is the output of ssh -v -i <key> user@host?

Comment: The question was edited, adding the output.

Comment: I gave up... and started all over again.